# Prevent anchor link from being added to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tabbed content box that when a tab is clicked, a '#div1' is appended to the end of my URL. Is there a way of preventing jQuery from doing this?

I still can't get it to work. I've made a fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/k6Ks8/

Comment: Please take more care over your posts. Punctuation matters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure, `event.preventDefault()` is what you are looking for.

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: What if you want the link still to work but don't want the URL to change?

Comment: @egr103 if I understood you correctly, only way to reload page content is using `onClick` handler along with `href` attribute

Answer (score 3):

easy

```
    $(function(){
        $('a[href="#"]').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```